# Access home server through through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

I know my machine is behind [CG NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), so I'm unable to do port forwarding. My router doesn't have built in VPN support. It is still possible to access my home server through VPN without port forwarding.

How can I identify a good VPN I can use?

Comment: What OS will your client devices be running? (They'll need to connect to the same VPN.)

Comment: @grawity Ubuntu server LTS 18.04

Answer (score 0):

VPN is not necessary if your only requirement is to have access to your home server. You can use Teamviewer or similar products for access.